# Perfect powers in Horadam sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, perfect-powers

The [Horadam sequence](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HoradamSequence.html) $\{W_n\}$ is defined by the Binet formula [*Using [notation from here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.05931.pdf)*]:

$$W_n=\frac{A\alpha^n-B\beta^n}{\alpha-\beta}$$

where,

$$A\ =\ b\ -\ a\beta \text{ and } B\ =\ b\ -a\alpha$$

$$\alpha = {p + d \over 2}, \beta = {p - d \over 2}, d = \sqrt {p^2 - 4q}$$

**Questions:**

Take all $a,b,\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$.

1. Does $W_n$ ever equal a perfect power? Since the Horadam sequence is a generalization of Fibonnacci, Lucas sequences, there are a finite set of perfect power values assumed by $W_n$. Can we say anything about perfect powers in general for $A, B, \alpha, \beta$ that defines $W_n$?
2. If we take $A = \alpha, B = \beta$ and $GCD(\alpha, \beta) = 1$, is $W_n$ ever a power of $\alpha - \beta$? [***Note:*** This is a special case of Beal's conjecture. So, the answer is likely to be $W_n$ is never a power of $\alpha - \beta$.]

For the second question, I tried $\beta = 1$ and set $W_n = y^m$ and obtained the Nagell-Ljunggren equation:

$$y^m = {\alpha^{n+1} - \beta^{n+1} \over \alpha - \beta} = {\alpha^{n+1} - 1 \over \alpha - 1}$$

with solutions $(\alpha, n+1, y, m) \in \{(3,5,11,2), (7,4,20,2), (18,3,7,3)\}$

What can we say about $\alpha \ne 1, \beta \ne 1$?

Comment: Your first question seems far too broad; there are many, *many* ways to get perfect powers. You can simply take a perfect power as a starting value, or simply retrace a sequence by declaring $W_n=p^k$, picking $W_{n-1}$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and counting backward. Or you could take an arbitrary such sequence and scale it so that a particular term is scaled up to a perfect power.

Comment: Also, are your expressions for $A$ and $B$ correct? The asymmetry seems odd to me, but you haven't explained where any of the variables come from. What is the recursion that defines the sequence, and what are the initial values?

Comment: @Servaes: I've added clarification for $\alpha, \beta$ and link to notation reference.

Comment: In your second question you require $\gcd(\alpha,\beta)=1$. Do you require $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be integers? In general, for such linear recurrences with integer coefficients $\alpha$ and $\beta$ need not be integers.

Comment: You are right about $\alpha, \beta$ not necessarily integers for the general Horadam sequence as seen in the Binet formula for Fibonnacci series. My second question is for integral $\alpha \ne 1, \beta \ne 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A=\alpha$ and $B=\beta$ then
$$W_n=\frac{\alpha^{n+1}-\beta^{n+1}}{\alpha-\beta}=\sum_{i=0}^n\alpha^i\beta^{n-i}.$$
In particular, for $n=1$ this becomes $W_1=\alpha+\beta$, which is clearly a perfect power for plenty of choices of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. For $n=2$ this becomes
$$W_2=\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2,$$
and for example for $\alpha=8$ and $\beta=7$ this becomes
$$W_2=\alpha^2+\alpha\beta+\beta^2=8^2+8\times7+7^2=13^2.$$